# Gradient descent residual

Tags: python, numerical-methods, gradient-descent, convergence

I've implemented the gradient descent method for finding roots of a system of nonlinear equations and I am wondering how the residual is determined? Is the residual simply the Euclidean norm (2-norm) which is `norm(F,2)`? I am trying to plot the residual to see the changes over time but I am quite confused about the term and how you calculate it. If my assumption of `norm(F,2)` being the residual is correct, I have plotted it and shown it below. If my understand is correct, this shows the algorithm stalling as there is no significant decrease in error each iteration after around iteration 1, resulting in this flat line after the first iteration?

```
import numpy as np
import array
from numpy.linalg import norm

def gradient_descent(fnon, jac, x0, tol, maxk, maxm, *args):
    k = 0
    x = x0

    F = eval(fnon)(x,*args)

    residuals = []
    arr = []
    arr.append(x)
    
    while (norm(F,2) > tol and k <= maxk):
        J = eval(jac)(x,2,fnon,F,*args)
        delta = -2 * np.matmul(np.transpose(J), F) #
        residuals.append(norm(F,2))
        lamb = 0.01       
        x = x + lamb * delta
        F = eval(fnon)(x,*args)
        arr.append(x)
        k += 1
    if (k >= maxk):
        print('No root found')
    else:
        print('Found root: ')
        print(x)
        
    return(are), residuals

def system(x):
    F = np.zeros((2,1), dtype=np.float64)
    F[0] = x[0]*x[0] + 2*x[1]*x[1] + math.sin(2*x[0])
    F[1] = x[0]*x[0] + math.cos(x[0]+5*x[1]) - 1.2
    return F

def jacob(x,n,fnon,F0,*args):
    J = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.float64)
    J[0,0] = 2*(x[0]+math.cos(2*x[0]))
    J[0,1] = 4*x[1]
    J[1,0] = 2*x[0]-math.sin(x[0]+5*x[1])
    J[1,1] = -5*math.sin(x[0]+5*x[1])
    return J

arr, residuals = gradient_descent('system', 'jacob', np.array([[-2],[-1]]), 1e-2, 20, 0)
```

Plotting norm:

[image: Plotting norm(F,2)]

Comment: It looks like residuals is not filled in your `gradient_descent` function, are you sure about your code?

Comment: @CésarDebeunne Thanks for the reply! I have updated the code. I didn't add it in the code to begin with because I was unsure if it was correct. Is norm(F,2) considered the residual?

Comment: In that case no. If it was the residual, you would have included it in your jacobian computation. The residual is simply the difference between your goal and the current value: here your goal is [0;0] so the residual is the value of the function